# Passing Access_Token from one activity to another

Tags: android, facebook

I want to achieve the simple task of having the user go through Facebook SSO process on the first activity and having their name display on the second activity. Here's my code.

Snippet from First Activity (Bundle made to pass token)

```
if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        Intent newPage = new Intent(
                PreLogin.this, PostLogin.class);
        Bundle tokenBundle = new Bundle();
        tokenBundle.putString("token", facebook.getAccessToken());
        newPage.putExtras(tokenBundle);
        startActivity(newPage);
```

Second Activity On Create method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.postlogin);
    myName = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

    Bundle tokenBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String access_token = tokenBundle.getString("token");

    facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
}
```

Second Activity IDRequestListener Method

```
private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        try {

            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

            final String name = json.getString("name");
            PostLogin.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myName.setText("Welcome: " + name);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        } catch (FacebookError e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        Log.w("WARNING", "IOException");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }

}
```

My textview does not get changed and when the program comes into the IDRequestListener method it gets the exception where I wrote to the log. Any suggestions for why the run() method does not get called?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception being thrown? Is it catched in one of the catch clauses in the *onComplete* method, or is one of the failure methods being called?

Comment: the failure method "onIOException", onComplete() does not get called which is the problem

Comment: Ok, and what is the error message in the exception? Try to do this: *Log.w("WARNING", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());*

Comment: Thanks! I was missing an internet permission, whoops..

Comment: Please put your last comment as an answer so that we can see that you solved the problem.